# Cache block tag size

Tags: c, caching, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a cache simulation program in C on linux using gcc as the compiler and I'm done for the most part. Only a few test cases go wrong (a few things out of the thousands of fed addresses that should be hitting are missing). I specify the cache properties on the command line. I suspect the error within my code has to do with the tag (if things aren't hitting then their tags aren't matching up when they should be). So my question is: Am I calculating the tag right?

```
//setting sizes of bits
int offsetSize = log2(lineSize);
int indexSize = 0;
if (strcmp(associativity,"direct") == 0){//direct associativity
  indexSize = log2(numLines);
}else if (assocNum == numLines){//fully associative
  indexSize = 0;
}else{//set associative
  indexSize = log2(assocNum);
}

address = (int) strtol(readAddress,&eptr,16);
unsigned long long int mask = 0;

//get the offset Bits
mask = (1 << offsetSize) - 1;
offsetBits = address & mask;

//get the index bits
mask = (1 << (indexSize)) - 1;
mask = mask << offsetSize;
indexBits = (address & mask) >> offsetSize;

//get tag bits
tagBits = address >> (offsetSize+indexSize);
```

The addresses that are being fed are usually 48 bits, so the variables address and mask is of type unsigned long long int. I think the problem I'm having is that I'm taking all the upper bits of the address, when I should only be taking a small set of bits from the large address.

For example: I have 32 cache lines in a 4-way set associative cache with a block size of 4.

offsetSize = log2(4) = 2

indexSize = log2(4) = 2

My code currently takes the upper bits of the address no matter the address size, minus the last 4 bits. Should I be taking only the upper 28 bits instead? (tagSize = (8*4)-3-2)

Comment: Based on your example, I'd say you have 1024 bytes of cache. 4 ways x 32 lines/way x 8 bytes/line. Which means that the tags should be 40 bits. But note that there are 4 tags for each combination of the lower 8 bits.

Comment: The cache size in that example would be 256, right? 32 lines*8 block size, the 4 is just how many lines are in a set, so it doesn't contribute to the size

Comment: That's a question that only you can answer (it depends on your definition of the cache parameters). If the total number of bytes in the cache is 256 divided into 4 ways, then you have 6 bits of useful address, and the tags need to be 42 bits.

Comment: So the tag doesn't depend on the block size? I guess a way to rephrase my question from above is should the size of the tag be the number of bits left over in the address after the index and offset are extracted, regardless of block size? (even if it's smaller than the address size)

Comment: Given that the addresses are 48 bits, the tag size is either 40 bits or 42 bits, depending on whether you have 4 sets with 32 lines each, or 32 lines total divided into 4 sets.

Comment: 4-way associative makes it 32 lines total, with 4 lines in a set (8 sets). I changed the example to a line size of 4 (cache size is 128) so the question is clearer in the sense that I don't know what to do if the entire address can't fit in the block size (48 bit address, 28 bit tag size(I think))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My code currently takes the upper bits of the address no matter the address size, minus the last 4 bits. Should I be taking only the upper 28 bits instead?

The tag has to contain all upper bits so that the tag can be used to determine if it is or isn't a cache hit.

If addresses are 48-bits and are split into 3 fields, you'd have a 2-bit "offset in cache line" field, a 2-bit "index in cache" field and a 44-bit "upper bits that have to be stored in the tag" field. If you only store 28 bits in the tag then you get cache hits when you should get cache misses (because the entry in the cache happens to contain data for a different address where the 28 bits happened to match).

Note that you can/should think of "associativity" as the number of sets of cache lines that happen to operate in parallel (where direct mapped is just "associativity = 1", and where fully associative is just "associativity = total_cache_size / cache_line_size"). The associativity has no direct effect on the index size (only the size of the sets of cache lines matters for index size), and the problem you're having is probably related to `indexSize = log2(assocNum);` (which doesn't make sense).

In other words:

```
    if( direct_mapped ) {
        associativity = 1;
    } else {
        max_associativity = total_cache_size / cache_line_size;
        if( fully_associative || (associativity > max_associativity) ) {
            associativity = max_associativity;
        }
    }

    set_size = total_cache_size / associativity;
    number_of_lines_in_set = set_size / cache_line_size;

    offset_size = log2(cache_line_size);
    index_size = log2(number_of_lines_in_set);
    tag_size = address_size - index_size - offsetSize;
```

Comment: I didn't really mention it but assocNum is 1 if it's direct associativity, and equal to the number of lines (cache size/ cache line size) if it's fully associative. Also, correct me if I'm wrong but I think the associativity has a direct effect on the index size. If I have 8 sets, I only need 3 bits to figure out which set an address maps to log2(number of sets). It indexes an address to a certain set, not a cache line within a set.

Comment: @Scerzyy: If you have one set of 256 (4-byte) cache lines then index size is 8 bits (because `log2(256) = 8`). If you have "associativity = N" then you have N sets of 256 (4-byte) cache lines and index size is still 8 bits (because `log2(256) = 8`).

Comment: @Scerzyy:  Mostly; associativity doesn't directly effect the index size; however (if you calculate set size from total cache size and don't calculate total cache size from set size) it does directly effect the number of cache lines in a set of cache lines (`set_size = total_cache_size / associativity;`) and the number of cache lines in a set directly effects the index size, so associativity does indirectly (but not directly) effect index size.

Comment: The set size is the associativity. An N-way associative cache has N lines per set, not N sets. So the set size and associativity are the same variable in my code (assocNum). Total cache size/associativity would give you the size of the set in terms of bytes, not cache lines. I looked it up again in case I was speaking gibberish this entire time. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_Placement_Policies#Set_Associative_Cache

Comment: @Scerzyy: Wikipedia is "wrong" (uses definitions that are more confusing than necessary); but even with their wonky definitions associativity doesn't directly effect index size (it'd still be "`index_size = log2( (total_cache_size / associativity) / cache_line_size)`" regardless of how you feel like defining "set" and would never be `indexSize = log2(assocNum);`).

Comment: I love you, you're absolutely right. Thank you so much.

Comment: I was so focused on explaining what the association of a cache is that I didn't even realize I was doing exactly what I was saying was wrong.